# Arquillian + embedded glassfish won't start

Tags: java, server, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to run a simple test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UserDAOBeanTest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(EnterpriseArchive.class, new File("D:\\ear.ear"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvite() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

But after running it i'm getting te following output in the console:

```
m 16, 2016 11:07:23 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup run
SEVERE: Startup service failed to start :     com.sun.enterprise.naming.GlassFishNamingBuilder
m 16, 2016 11:07:23 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer doExecute
INFO: Server shutdown initiated
```

I cannot figure out what causes this unexpected shutdown. Can you please help me with that? Where should I look for the solution? I would also much appreciate it if you help me to find the log file of the embedded glassfish server.

**FOLLOW UP**

My arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

In glassfish-resources.xml I configured access to my database.

Comment: What's in the arquillian.xml? Has the app server been configured?

Comment: I added my arquillian.xml to the question text

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log? Is it possible to start the app server any other way to see if it works?

Comment: I don't see any exceptions in console output.  I can run a regular glassfish server and it works just fiine. But I have to run embedded server for tests.

Comment: Can you run the embedded server not using arquillian to make sure it's working?

Comment: I cannot run embedded server outside test context since Intellij Idea asks me to to specify test class.

Comment: Try using the command line: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1754/gihyh/index.html

Comment: First of all, please try a remote or managed GlassFish instead of embedded one. They are much more reliable...

Comment: One additional missing bit to get the full picture is your `pom.xml` or anything else you use for your dependency management.